# How get api error message in Flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible get error message when call rest api in flutter?

Eg.

print(response.statusCode); --return code

How print this error message?

```
The request could not be processed because an error occurred whilst attempting to evaluate the SQL statement associated with this resource. Please check the SQL statement is
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dio package you can catch DioError and fetch a response from the error.
In my case back returns me the message in ['error'][''message].
I'm not sure how it works with http package. Firstly you can print e.response!.data to see the structure and then get the error text

```
try {
//make request
} on DioError catch (e, stacktrace) {
  final result = e.response!.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print(result['error']['message']); <---- getting error message from response 
}
```

Comment: Tnx for help but now I don't use DIO! Maybe in future I will try!